# How to understand meaning of a Canon EDSDK error code?

Tags: c#, canon-sdk

So far I have not found any documentation for error codes in Canon EDSDK.

In the examples that come with the SDK the error code is always compared to some particular errors making sense in that particular situation, like that:

```
//Notification of error
if (err != EDSDKLib.EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
{
    // It retries it at device busy
    if (err == EDSDKLib.EDSDK.EDS_ERR_DEVICE_BUSY)
    {
     ...
```

I, on the other hand, want to know the meaning of an arbitrary error I get. How do I do this? I am using C# if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, the documentation explains how to do it.
For anybody else struggling:

1. turn your error from dec into hex
2. open EDSDKErrors.h
3. find your error
4. if it's not explicit enough, open the documentation (EDSDK_API_EN.pdf)
5. search for the *name* of your error and hopefully get a better description